# youtube-dl downloads create .temp.mp4 files when content already exist locally. ffmpeg issue?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, download, video-conversion

When I try to download content from twitch.tv who I already had in the working directly, the process create an .temp.mp4 file and it seem to be created by an ffmpeg process.

If the content doesn’t already exist, it download normally.

When using verbose -v I get an error message saying: “[ffmpeg] Fixing malformed AAC bitstream in”

This is the command syntax:

```
root@hosted:/mnt/disk1/twitch/markilokurasy# youtube-dl -v -i --no-overwrites https://www.twitch.tv/markilokurasy/videos/all
```

This is the verbose:

```
[debug] System config: []
[debug] User config: []
[debug] Custom config: []
[debug] Command-line args: [u'-v', u'-i', u'--no-overwrites', u'https://www.twitch.tv/markilokurasy/videos/all']
[debug] Encodings: locale UTF-8, fs UTF-8, out UTF-8, pref UTF-8
[debug] youtube-dl version 2019.01.10
[debug] Python version 2.7.15rc1 (CPython) - Linux-4.15.0-29-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic
[debug] exe versions: ffmpeg 3.4.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.1, ffprobe 3.4.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
[debug] Proxy map: {}
[twitch:videos:all] markilokurasy: Downloading channel info JSON
[twitch:videos:all] markilokurasy: Downloading all videos JSON page 1
[download] Downloading playlist: MarkiLokurasY
[twitch:videos:all] playlist MarkiLokurasY: Collected 76 video ids (downloading 76 of them)
[download] Downloading video 1 of 76
[twitch:vod] 362193684: Downloading vod info JSON
[twitch:vod] 362193684: Downloading vod access token
[twitch:vod] 362193684: Downloading m3u8 information
[debug] Default format spec: bestvideo+bestaudio/best
[debug] Invoking downloader on u'https://vod-secure.twitch.tv/75937e2657f777b6955b_markilokurasy_32122011088_1076251126/chunked/index-muted-UO5C2PH170.m3u8'
[download] SSomos viernessssss _ ig - @markigang-v362193684.mp4 has already been downloaded
[download] 100% of 9.76GiB
[debug] ffmpeg command line: ffprobe -show_streams 'file:SSomos viernessssss _ ig - @markigang-v362193684.mp4'
[ffmpeg] Fixing malformed AAC bitstream in "SSomos viernessssss _ ig - @markigang-v362193684.mp4"
[debug] ffmpeg command line: ffmpeg -y -i 'file:SSomos viernessssss _ ig - @markigang-v362193684.mp4' -c copy -f mp4 '-bsf:a' aac_adtstoasc 'file:SSomos viernessssss _ ig - @markigang-v362193684.temp.mp4'
^C
ERROR: Interrupted by user
```

What do you suggest to use like tag to avoid this. Please not the .mp4 videos files are plenty playable with audio when I play them after.

Comment: Not related to ffmpeg. The command is generated by yt-dl. When the target file already exists, what should happen?

Comment: I'm not sure what your actual question is. Do you want to overwrite existing files? What's the problem with having a temporary file created?

Comment: This is a bug report for yt-dlp project, not a question.